# Should I include a search box in the dropdown menu or just go with one in the nagivation bar?

Tags: gui-design, search, e-commerce

So i'm designing the interface of an ecommerce website that acts as a platform for stores, and naturally, there's a search box in the navigation menu.

For each of the elements in the navigation bar, there's a dropdown menu with the subcategories (e.g. Electronics -> Phone, Tablets, etc.).

One of the elements in the navigation bar is called stores, and the dropdown lists the stores per category.

If I want to allow people to search for a specific store, should I include a search box in the dropdown menu, or is the one in the navigation bar enough?

On the one hand, I want to avoid repeating the same element, but on the other, I want it to be real easy for users to find a specific store.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest some similar to Amazon approach: a search bar, which **let users constraint the search and then categories**.
In the categories menu if you can't show them all, you can just an option like "See all categories", which could redirect to a new pages with more options to navegate those categories.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, I see what you mean, and I thought of doing that. I've already added a 'view all' button in the dropdown menu. Would it be useless to add another search bar right beneath that?

Comment: Maybe not useless, but not really necessary. You also have to consider conventions and mental models when designing a site of a particular kind -ecommerce here- in order to offer a natural flow for the user. 
If I'm searching for a particular product, let's say sennheiser headphones red edition I will use the search bar supposing that the search does its job well, and if Im searching for headphones in general I could go to that category nav-dropdown, and once I'm redirected, filter as I want with no constraints.

Comment: Adding a new search in inside each nav item, will add complexity to a control which is not usually used for that, and adds some question as "where are you showing the results?" , "the search is based on the options that Im seeing or on all possible options?" "what happen if the search gives no results, do you have to press a button to return to normal navigation list?" etc.

Comment: My upvote especially for your comments, you should incorporate them in your answer!